Checking which overload function mypy matches
When using type hints in Python with mypy, I often encounter the error Overload function overlap with incompatible return types. I am trying to better understand, how mypy matches which overload function and in that regards, I have the following piece of code:
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def foo(x: str, y: str, z: Literal[True]) -> int: ...

@overload
def foo(x: str, y: str, z: Literal[False]) -> str: ...

@overload
def foo(x: str = ..., y: str = ..., z: Literal[False] = ...) -> str: ...

@overload
def foo(*, x: str = ..., y: str = ..., z: Literal[True]) -> int: ...

def foo(x: str = "a", y: str = "b", z: bool = False) -> str | int:
    if z:
        return 1
    else:
        return x + y

foo()  # matches 3rd overload
foo(z=True)  # matches 4th overload
foo(z=False)  # matches 3rd overload
foo(x="a", z=True)  # matches 4th overload
foo("a", "b", True)  # matches 1st overload
foo(x="a", z=False)  # matches 3rd overload
foo("a", "b", False)  # matches 2nd overload
foo("a", y="b", z=True)  # matches 4th overload
foo("a", y="c", z=False)  # matches 3rd overload

This piece of code doesn't fail with mypy. However, I am not sure if I am able to infer correctly which overload function is matching to which invocation (although, I have added comments, but most likely they are incorrect).
Is it possible to see, which overload function mypy is picking, when the function is invoked?

Is this really the best approach here? At this point it might be easier to have separate functions

Agreed, this might not be the best approach, but my intention is to understand more clearly how mypy matches overload functions.

I think only the last two are incorrect; they match 1 and 2, respectively, due to the overloads' orders. Pyright agrees with this (indirect link, snippet is too long). There are two ways to make Pyright output the overload signature: hover the function name in the call context, and use a helper (f: (*P.args, **P.kwargs) -> T, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T. Neither works with Mypy.

One approach is to install a non-compiled version of mypy (pip uninstall mypy; pip install mypy --no-binary mypy), trigger an overload error to find out where in the code it loops over the overloads, make the loop enumerate, then insert a print statement for each overload which falls through. If you then run mypy on the command line, it'll display your print statement. A mypy plugin could also possibly work.
